# nyc not recognized as command after installation

Tags: node.js, npm, istanbul, nyc

I am very new to node.js, npm and JavaScript but for code coverage trying with Istanbul tool and hence installed `nyc` with `npm i nyc` referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc which outputs like

```
C:\Users\user>npm i nyc
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.

+ nyc@15.1.0
updated 1 package in 1.334s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

But when I hit `nyc` o command prompt, it says - nyc is not recognized as internal or external command.

As per doc, I added dev dependency with following but seeing same error.

```
C:\Users\user>npm i -D nyc
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.

+ nyc@15.1.0
added 142 packages from 99 contributors in 48.325s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Please guide me what is wrong here.

Comment: there is any `package.json` file at `C:\Users\user\` ?

Comment: No,it is not there. I'm not able to get where to get it from and what should be the content

Answer (score 2):

you can try `npm install -g nyc` in case you want to save in globally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you mean `npm install -g nyc` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to make this work

1. Install `nyc` as a dev-dependency
2. Install `nyc` as a global dependency

**NOTE:** For me installing it as a dev-dependency is much better.

Let's run `npm i nyc -D` . What is this going to do? This is going to locate this package in your package.json, and node_modules. The reason you can't run it through cli, is the fact that it's not registered in system variables. So how do we run it, you might say? We create a [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts) in package.json

```json
scripts:{
  "nyc: "nyc"
}
```

And to run it, just `npm run nyc`

Now let's install it as a global dependency. Installing a package as a global dependency, means we don't add the package to our package.json, and node_modules, but if it's CLI, then it registers itself as a system variable.

```
npm i -g nyc
nyc
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the root folder of your project.
Run `npm init`, this will create the package.json file.
Then run `npm i nyc`.

If you want to install it as a dev dependency use below command.

```
npm install --save-dev nyc
```

Comment: I did `npm init -y` and then `npm i nyc` but still for `nyc` on command prompt, gives same error.

Comment: We have installed nyc as devDependency. You should write your command i.e `nyc` in package.json scripts section and run it using `npm run <script-name>` command. For detailed info please read this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc#installation--usage).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was because I had a space in my windows user name. It was "firstName lastName".

I have two solutions for that.

1. You can install wsl and Ubuntu LTE from win store and then add extensions to visual code, so you will be able to run Linux terminal. It will hoverer require to install node for Linux and all other staff.
2. You can create new windows user and use VS Code in 'run as' mode. (shift and right-click). If you don't have your VS Code installed for all users then you would have to add access for this newly created user.

I went with the second solution and it worked for me.